# parameterization of a part of a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametrization

I have to parametrize $D=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 25,y\le -4\}$.

- I can see the I have to parametrize 2 surfaces :

  - ($S_1$) the intersection between the plane $z=-4$ and the sphere: ($x^2+z^2\le 9$)
  - ($S_2$) The part of the sphere between $-5\le y \le -4$

$(S_1)$ should be :

$r(u,v)=(u\cos(v),-4,u\sin(v))$

$0\le u \le 3$

$0\le v \le 2\pi$

$(S_2)$, I need help with this, Can you help me find out $\phi,\theta$

$r(\phi,\theta)=(5\sin\phi \cos\theta,...,5\sin\phi \sin\theta)$(x,z might be wrong)

EDIT:

I know that the parametrization of a sphere of radius 5 is : $r(\phi,\theta)=(5\sin\phi \cos\theta,5\sin\phi \sin\theta,5\cos\phi)$

Comment: If you use `\sin` and `\cos` in your MathJax, your formatting will look a lot better.

Comment: $S_1:r(u,v)=(u\cos(v),-4,u\sin(v))$

Comment: As for your other surface, I am tempted to say plug in $ x = 5 \sin \phi \cos \theta, z = 5 \sin \phi \sin \theta$ into $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 25$  I also wonder how you know that those the correct parameterization for spherical coordinates without knowing the 3rd coordinate.  Then I think I should just let you off the hook, $y = cos\phi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it is you need to parametrize the solid bounded by the sphere of radius $5$ and the plane $y=-4$. Here is how I would proceed :

Use spherical coordinates as follows : let $y=\rho \cos \phi$, $z=\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta$ and $x=\rho \sin \phi \sin \theta$, such that the sphere has equation
$$
\rho =5,
$$
and the plane $y=-4$ has equation
$$
\rho \cos \phi=-4
$$

Now things become easy. The projection of the solid in the $yz$ plane is the domain
$$
D= \{(\rho,\phi)\;|\; \frac{4}{  \cos \phi} \le \rho \le 5 , \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{-4}{5}\right)\le \phi \le \pi\}
$$
And it follows that
$$
E = \{(\rho,\phi,\theta )\;|\;(\rho,\phi) \in D, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi \}
$$

Comment: why is $\rho$ between $4/ \cos\phi$ and $5$ ? Isn't the radius of the sphere constant ?

Comment: The radius of the sphere is constant indeed ($=5$). But you want the inside of the sphere too, between the plane and the sphere.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, your parametrization is both $S_1$ and $S_2$ ? so it includes the plane and the sphere? becouse I want to calculate the flux, so I think I should have two surfaces because they have different normals

Comment: My parametrization is the solid bounded by $S_1$ and $S_2$, so yes it does include the plane and the sphere (which are the borders of this solid). My suggestion : post a new question with the entire question, not just the parametrization part. To compute the flux there are different ways, but selecting the best way requires the entire question and the context.